# Which formate notifications should be send to FCM server for push notifications?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, firebase, rubygems, firebase-cloud-messaging, google-cloud-messaging

I have implemented push noticiation to send gem in FCM server.

GemFile:

```
gem 'fcm'
gem 'httparty'
gem 'google-api-client'
gem 'google-apis-fcm_v1'
gem 'googleauth'
```

The setup:

config/initializers/fcm.rb

```
# frozen_string_literal: true

require 'google/apis/fcm_v1'
require 'googleauth'
require 'googleauth/stores/file_token_store'
require 'fileutils'

# Load the JSON credentials file you downloaded earlier
credentials_path = 'byl-stg-firebase-adminsdk-iaso9-6d7da9d2fe.json'

FCM_SERVICE = Google::Apis::FcmV1::FirebaseCloudMessagingService.new
FCM_SERVICE.authorization = Google::Auth::ServiceAccountCredentials.make_creds(
  json_key_io: File.open(credentials_path).to_io,
  scope: 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/firebase.messaging'
)

# Set the FCM API endpoint
FCM_API_ENDPOINT = 'projects/byl-stg'
```

I am sending notifications from service class:

app/services/notifications/create_service.rb

```
# frozen_string_literal: true

require 'google/apis/fcm_v1'

module Notifications
  class CreateService < BaseService
    def call
      notification_data = Notification.create(notification_attributes)
      # def create_fcm_message(registration_token, notification_data)
      create_fcm_message(FcmToken.first.token, notification_data)
    end

    def notification_attributes
      {
        message: 'Diwuhferkuf',
        sound: 'default',
        user_id: fetch_user_ids
      }
    end

    def create_fcm_message(registration_token, notification_data)
      fcm_message = Google::Apis::FcmV1::Message.new(
        notification: Google::Apis::FcmV1::Notification.new(
          title: 'Notification Title',
          body: notification_data[:message]
        ),
        token: registration_token
      )
      FCM_SERVICE.send_message(FCM_API_ENDPOINT, fcm_message)
    end
```

after running this : FCM_SERVICE.send_message(FCM_API_ENDPOINT, fcm_message)

It's giving me error:

```
[4] pry(#<Notifications::CreateService>)> FCM_SERVICE.send_message(FCM_API_ENDPOINT, fcm_message) 
Sending HTTP post https://fcm.googleapis.com/v1/projects/byl-stg/messages:send?
400
Error - #<Google::Apis::ClientError: INVALID_ARGUMENT: The message is not set. status_code: 400 header: #<HTTP::Message::Headers:0x00000001120d8028 @http_version="1.1", @body_size=0, @chunked=false, @request_method="POST", @request_uri=#<Addressable::URI:0xa8c0 URI:https://fcm.googleapis.com/v1/projects/byl-stg/messages:send?>, @request_query=nil, @request_absolute_uri=nil, @status_code=400, @reason_phrase="Bad Request", @body_type=nil, @body_charset=nil, @body_date=nil, @body_encoding=#<Encoding:UTF-8>, @is_request=false, @header_item=[["Vary", "Origin"], ["Vary", "X-Origin"], ["Vary", "Referer"], ["Content-Type", "application/json; charset=UTF-8"], ["Content-Encoding", "gzip"], ["Date", "Tue, 15 Aug 2023 10:34:40 GMT"], ["Server", "scaffolding on HTTPServer2"], ["Cache-Control", "private"], ["X-XSS-Protection", "0"], ["X-Frame-Options", "SAMEORIGIN"], ["X-Content-Type-Options", "nosniff"], ["Alt-Svc", "h3=\":443\"; ma=2592000,h3-29=\":443\"; ma=2592000"], ["Transfer-Encoding", "chunked"]], @dumped=false> body: "{\n  \"error\": {\n    \"code\": 400,\n    \"message\": \"The message is not set.\",\n    \"status\": \"INVALID_ARGUMENT\",\n    \"details\": [\n      {\n        \"@type\": \"type.googleapis.com/google.rpc.BadRequest\",\n        \"fieldViolations\": [\n          {\n            \"field\": \"message\",\n            \"description\": \"The message is not set.\"\n          }\n        ]\n      },\n      {\n        \"@type\": \"type.googleapis.com/google.firebase.fcm.v1.FcmError\",\n        \"errorCode\": \"INVALID_ARGUMENT\"\n      }\n    ]\n  }\n}\n">
```

1. I am expecting it should hit the server with the notifications.
2. I want to set token for each user while logging in otherwise FE need to send token for notifications before trigger.